# How to perform a join using nhibernate in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Hi i want to perform a join between to tables but i am not able to do it.

Here is my classes:

```
 public class Person
{
   public virtual LoginAccount LoginAccount { get; set; }
}

 public class LoginAccount 
{
 //fields of LoginAccount
}
```

Mapping file of Person

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly ="HobbyHomes" namespace ="HobbyHomes.Model" >
<class name ="Person">

<composite-id class="HobbyHomes.Model.LoginAccount" name="LoginAccount">
  <key-property name="LoginAccountID">
    <column name="LoginAccountID"></column>
  </key-property>
</composite-id>

//other properties

 </class>
```

Now what this is what i tried to fetch values of LoginAccount from Person:

```
  public IList<Person> FetchPerson(ICollection<Learner> learner)
    {
        log.Debug("Started");
        ISession session = DataAccessLayerHelper.OpenReaderSession();
        IList<Person> person = null;
        ITransaction transaction = null;
        Disjunction dj = new Disjunction();
        try
        {
            transaction = session.BeginTransaction();


            person = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person), "person")
                            .CreateCriteria("person.LoginAccount", "LoginAccount", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                            .List<Person>();
            transaction.Commit();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
                transaction.Rollback();
            log.Error(ex);

        }
        finally
        {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.Dispose();

            if (session != null && session.IsConnected)
                session.Close();
        }

        log.Debug("End");
        return person;
    }
```

but with this i am only able to fetch the fields of Person Class and  not the fields of LoginAccount class.Please Help me.

Comment: This may help you get going. http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/05/querying-with-nhibernate.aspx

Comment: I personally use the QueryOver API. You make want to look in to that as well. It may save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

`person = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person), "person").List<Person>()` should give you all properties since the column `LoginAccountID` is part of the person table.

maybe what you want is a keyreference

```
<composite-id>
  <key-many-to-one class="HobbyHomes.Model.LoginAccount" name="LoginAccount">
    <column name="LoginAccountID"></column>
  </key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>
```